# Is there a way to bitwise-OR enums in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I'm using a state machine, and the code's getting really verbose when testing against a large number of possible states.

```
enum Mood {
    HAPPY, SAD, CALM, SLEEPY, OPTIMISTIC, PENSIVE, ENERGETIC;
}
```

Is there any way to do this:

```
if (currentMood == (HAPPY | OPTIMISTIC | ENERGETIC) {}
```

Instead of this:

```
if (currentMood == HAPPY || currentMood == OPTIMISTIC || currentMood == ENERGETIC) {}
```

Or would it be better to stick with integers and flags in this case?

Comment: You mean `if ((currentMood & (HAPPY | OPTIMISTIC | ENERGETIC)) != 0) {}`. Or perhaps `if (((1<<currentMood) & ((1<<HAPPY) | (1<<OPTIMISTIC) | (1<<ENERGETIC))) != 0) {}`. Guess I'm happy you've got to do it properly.

Comment: I infer from "integers and flags" that one's currentMood may be more than one Mood.

Comment: @Tom - Yes, you're technically right. I was torn between writing in C-style bitwise operations or a set-theory type syntax.

Comment: @blizpasta - That wasn't my original intent, but it would be a useful generalisation. Sorry my title's a bit ambiguous there.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Maybe use something like [EnumSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)?

```
if (EnumSet<Mood>.of(HAPPY, OPTIMISTIC, ENERGETIC).contains(currentMood))
{ 
 //Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I think you even can drop the <Mood> in this case

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. IMO it's better than the switch-case approach because it's more concise.

Answer (score 18):

Give your enums an int attribute.

```
enum Mood {
    private int id;

    HAPPY(1), SAD(2), CALM(4), SLEEPY(8), OPTIMISTIC(16), PENSIVE(32), ENERGETIC(64);

    Mood( int id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

On the if, test against this atrribute.

```
if ( currentMood & ( HAPPY.id | OPTIMISTIC.id | ENERGETIC.id ) != 0 ) { ... }
```

Comment: If you're confident in the ordering in source code (a moderately large "if") you can also just use the `ordinal()`.

Comment: You can't use `ordinal()` because that would give you `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, etc., which will not work with bitwise `OR`.

Comment: A bit late response, but you probably can do `1 << ordinal()`

Comment: without a public getter, id should be final public.

Comment: You can use the ordinal() to create a unique "mask" values likes this ```1 << ordinal()``` as long as the enum has at most ```32``` constants which is usually the case. up to ```64``` you can use ```long``` typed masks. That is what EnumSet's implenentation do under the hood for small enums.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from other answers: if that particular set of states has a semantically defined meaning in your application (rather independent of your particular method, specific to the Enum) , I'd recommend to included that test as a method in the same Enum class.

```
enum Mood {
     HAPPY, SAD...

     public boolean isRatherPositive() {
       ....
     }

}
```

(or a static method) to be implemented by any of the logic suggested by the other answers (I'd favour the EnumSet, which could be statically o lazily instantiated).

To have the method in the Enum is useful to avoid code duplication, but above all, to prevent bugs in case you add members to the Enum or modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
switch(currentmood){
    case HAPPY:
    case OPTIMISTIC:...
        Then do this
        break;
    default://else
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach but could be given more context to relate better with the question

Answer (score 1):

You could give your enum a boolean flag and test for that.

```
enum Mood {
    HAPPY(true), SAD, CALM, SLEEPY, OPTIMISTIC(true), PENSIVE, ENERGETIC(true);
    final boolean good;

    Mood(){this(false);}

    Mood(boolean isgood){this.good = isgood;}

    public isGood(){return good;}
}
```

This way the check is short

```
if (currentMood.isGood()) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to have EnumSet/switch/if etc. This makes sense if you are classifying the enumeration in some way that is not intrinsically part of the enumeration itself. For example, whether a color is part of the national flag's color. The 'dependency model' is that national flag depends on Color, but Color doesn't care about the existence of national flags.

On the other hand, if you are trying to determine whether a color is a primary color or not (intrinsic to human model of color), then it belongs on the enum class itself. So,

```
enum Color {
  private final boolean _crtPrimary;

  Red(true), Green(true), Blue(true), Black(false)

  Color(boolean crtPrimary) {
    _crtPrimary = crtPrimary;
  }

  public boolean isCRTPrimary() {
    return _crtPrimary;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use || you have to specify both values you are comparing each time. You could easily write a small method to do this though.

```
if (currentMood.hasMood(HAPPY, OPTIMISTIC, ENERGETIC)) {}

public boolean hasMood(Mood ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use YourEnum.*values()*

For example, I have Class called *Enumerations*.
In it, I have multiple Enum Classes.

For example:

```
public class Enumerations {

public enum smtg
{
    Fast(1),
    Slow(2);

    private int number;
    private smtg(final int num) { number = num; }
    public int getsmtg()
    {
        return number;
    }
}
......
```

}

When I want to use bitwise, I just use it like that:

```
Enumerations.smtg.values()[Enumerations.smtg.Slow.ordinal() | Enumerations.smtg.Fast.ordinal()]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option:

```
public enum PaymentResponse {
    PP_SUCCESS, PP_FAILURE, CC_SUCCESS, CC_FAILURE;

    public boolean isSuccessful() {
            return ordinal() == CC_SUCCESS.ordinal()  ||  
                   ordinal() == PP_SUCCESS.ordinal() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just `return this == CC_SUCCESS || this == PP_SUCCESS;` ?

Comment: Agree with Wulf